# Android Dynamic Search inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement a search function inside one of my fragment, as the users types the list will become more defined and match the users input.

I had the code working in an activity but I am getting an error when trying to implement it within a fragment. I am getting an error with the below code snippet, saying that `.setFilterQueryProvider`cannot be resolved.

Can anyone point out where I may have gone wrong?

**Code Snippet**

```
    adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            return db.fetchRecipes(constraint.toString());
        }
    });
```

**Fragment containing snippet**

```
public class SearchRecipes extends ListFragment{

    private ListView lv;
    private static int finalHeat;
    private static String finalDietary;
    private static int finalTime;
    private static Cursor filterCursor;
    private static Cursor timeAnddietaryFilterCursor;
    private static Cursor heatAnddietaryFilterCursor;
    private static Cursor heatAndtimeFilterCursor;
    private static Cursor cursor;
    private static boolean filter;
    EditText inputSearch;
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCustomAdaper;



    public SearchRecipes() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_recipes, container, false);

        final DBMain db = new DBMain(getActivity());

        db.open();

        cursor = db.getAllRecipes();

        String[] values = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for(int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
        {
            String row = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("recipe_name"));
            values[i] = row;
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {


                // When user changed the Text
                adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                //myCursorAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                //dynamicSearch.this.myCustomAdaper.getFilter().filter(cs);
                //dynamicSearch.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                return db.fetchRecipes(constraint.toString());
            }
        });

        FloatingActionButton filterButton = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.filterButton);
        filterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // custom ingredient_dialog
                filter = false;
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.filter_dialog);
                dialog.setTitle("Add Ingredient");

                final Spinner heat = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.heatSpinner);
                heat.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                        String heat2 = heat.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        finalHeat = Integer.parseInt(heat2);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                        finalHeat = 0;
                    }
                });

                final Spinner dietary = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dietarySpinner);
                dietary.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                        finalDietary = dietary.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                        finalDietary = "";
                    }
                });

                final Spinner time = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.timeSpinner);
                time.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                        String time2 = time.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        finalTime = Integer.parseInt(time2);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                        finalTime = 0;
                    }
                });


                Button dialogButtonOk = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
                // if button is clicked, close the custom ingredient_dialog
                dialogButtonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (finalHeat != 0 && finalTime != 0 && finalDietary != "") {
                            //full filter search
                            filterCursor = db.fullFilter(finalHeat, finalDietary, finalTime);

                            String[] columns = new String[]{db.KEY_RECIPE_NAME, db.KEY_ID};

                            int[] to = new int[]{R.id.recipeName};

                            final SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.possible_recipe_row, filterCursor, columns, to, 0);
                            //myCursorAdapter.getFilter().filter();
                            //lv.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
                            //ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
                            //lv.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
                            setListAdapter(adapter);

                        }
                        if (finalHeat == 0 && finalTime != 0 && finalDietary != "") {
                            //filter for final time and dietary
                            timeAnddietaryFilterCursor = db.timeAnddietaryFilter(finalTime, finalDietary);
                            String[] columns = new String[]{db.KEY_RECIPE_NAME, db.KEY_ID};

                            int[] to = new int[]{R.id.recipeName};

                            final SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.possible_recipe_row, timeAnddietaryFilterCursor, columns, to, 0);
                            //myCursorAdapter.getFilter().filter();
                            //lv.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
                            //ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
                            //lv.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
                            setListAdapter(adapter);

                        }
                        if (finalHeat != 0 && finalTime == 0 && finalDietary != "") {
                            //filter for heat and dietary
                            heatAnddietaryFilterCursor = db.heatAnddietaryFilter(finalHeat, finalDietary);
                            String[] columns = new String[]{db.KEY_RECIPE_NAME, db.KEY_ID};

                            int[] to = new int[]{R.id.recipeName};

                            final SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.possible_recipe_row, heatAnddietaryFilterCursor, columns, to, 0);
                            //myCursorAdapter.getFilter().filter();
                            //lv.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
                            //ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
                            //lv.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
                            setListAdapter(adapter);

                        }
                        if (finalHeat != 0 && finalTime != 0 && finalDietary.length() > 1) {
                            //filter for heat and time
                            heatAndtimeFilterCursor = db.heatAndtimeFilter(finalHeat, finalTime);
                            String[] columns = new String[]{db.KEY_RECIPE_NAME, db.KEY_ID};

                            int[] to = new int[]{R.id.recipeName};

                            final SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.possible_recipe_row, heatAndtimeFilterCursor, columns, to, 0);
                            //myCursorAdapter.getFilter().filter();
                            //lv.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
                            //ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
                            //lv.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
                            setListAdapter(adapter);

                        } else {
                            String[] columns = new String[]{db.KEY_RECIPE_NAME, db.KEY_ID};
                            int[] to = new int[]{R.id.recipeName};

                            SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.possible_recipe_row, cursor, columns, to, 0);
                            //ListView recipeList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.possibleRecipeList);
                            //recipeList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
                            setListAdapter(adapter);

                        }

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        });



        return rootView;
    }

}
```

**Error Log**

```
Error:(101, 16) error: cannot find symbol method setFilterQueryProvider(<anonymous FilterQueryProvider>)
```

Comment: where is the error log?

Comment: Can you try `CursorAdapter` instead of `SimpleCursorAdapter`. It may help you.

Comment: your `adapter` is an `ArrayAdapter`, it has no `setFilterQueryProvider` method

Comment: I updated the question showing the error log, @pskink is there a method that I could use for an ArrayAdapter?

Comment: no,  just use SimpleCursorAdapter + FilterQueryProvider